# Linux LVM: move free space from a volume group to another

Tags: linux, lvm, centos5

I've just read 
"How can you re-allocate space from one Volume Group to another Volume Group in Linux?" [How can you re-allocate space from one Volume Group to another Volume Group in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/238487/how-can-you-re-allocate-space-from-one-volume-group-to-another-volume-group-in-l)
But I'm still confused.

I have inherited the managemnt of a linux NAS built with a 16 disk supermicro case, a 3ware 9650 RAID card and Centos 5.
There are three 2.73 TB raid units created by the 3ware board; auto-carving to 1.5TB is enabled so Centos sees six physical volumes.

Those 6 PVs are arranged in 2 volume groups and one of the VGs (volgroup1) has 2.15TB of free space.
I need to move those free 2.15TB to the other VG (volgroup2)
Then I need to assign those 2.15TB the ext3 partition on logical volume "mmedia0", without disruption of any other LV/filesystem.

The output of the relevant LVM commands follws.

Thanks in advance
Guido

```
[root@lt-nas1 ~]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sdd1   VG volgroup2   lvm2 [1.50 TB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdf1   VG volgroup2   lvm2 [1.50 TB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdg1   VG volgroup2   lvm2 [1.23 TB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdb1   VG volgroup1   lvm2 [1.50 TB / 1.00 TB free]
  PV /dev/sdc1   VG volgroup1   lvm2 [1.22 TB / 24.00 GB free]
  PV /dev/sde1   VG volgroup1   lvm2 [1.23 TB / 1.12 TB free]
  Total: 6 [8.18 TB] / in use: 6 [8.18 TB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

[root@lt-nas1 ~]# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  volgroup1   3   5   0 wz--n- 3.95T 2.15T
  volgroup2   3   3   0 wz--n- 4.23T    0

[root@lt-nas1 ~]# lvs
  LV               VG        Attr   LSize    Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  cli-bak          volgroup1 -wi-ao  515.88G
  fatt-dig         volgroup1 -wi-ao   10.00G
  fil-ut           volgroup1 -wi-ao  220.00G
  homes            volgroup1 -wi-ao  100.00G
  serv-bak         volgroup1 -wi-ao 1000.00G
  esxp-bak         volgroup2 -wi-ao    3.73T
  lt-services      volgroup2 -wi-ao   10.00G
  mmedia0          volgroup2 -wi-ao  501.97G


[root@lt-nas1 ~]# pvdisplay -m
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdd1
  VG Name               volgroup2
  PV Size               1.50 TB / not usable 31.88 MB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              49151
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          49151
  PV UUID               dj86xG-bVvy-e2KS-dxCb-oDTB-vqfB-oIFEFn

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 32767:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup2/esxp-bak
    Logical extents     89404 to 122171
  Physical extent 32768 to 33087:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup2/lt-services
    Logical extents     0 to 319
  Physical extent 33088 to 49150:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup2/mmedia0
    Logical extents     0 to 16062

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdf1
  VG Name               volgroup2
  PV Size               1.50 TB / not usable 29.98 MB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              49151
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          49151
  PV UUID               VzrYLh-qzGP-JlfN-WtUn-39Li-mq4Z-M4AlkY

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 49150:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup2/esxp-bak
    Logical extents     0 to 49150

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdg1
  VG Name               volgroup2
  PV Size               1.23 TB / not usable 27.98 MB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              40253
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          40253
  PV UUID               w2AczV-NUC1-K6xj-Qom6-NsNb-0mXk-o9a63M

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 40252:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup2/esxp-bak
    Logical extents     49151 to 89403

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               volgroup1
  PV Size               1.50 TB / not usable 31.88 MB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              49151
  Free PE               32832
  Allocated PE          16319
  PV UUID               Kilk0G-0qxl-ft2w-8iU7-abaa-u1n2-d9EHiO

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 32767:
    FREE
  Physical extent 32768 to 39167:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup1/fil-ut
    Logical extents     0 to 6399
  Physical extent 39168 to 39231:
    FREE
  Physical extent 39232 to 39871:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup1/fil-ut
    Logical extents     6400 to 7039
  Physical extent 39872 to 49150:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup1/cli-bak
    Logical extents     0 to 9278

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               volgroup1
  PV Size               1.22 TB / not usable 16.80 MB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              39997
  Free PE               768
  Allocated PE          39229
  PV UUID               EAtHL7-wraU-DdRP-d9Fq-xdrU-Wyf0-8PlCqj

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 31999:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup1/serv-bak
    Logical extents     0 to 31999
  Physical extent 32000 to 32767:
    FREE
  Physical extent 32768 to 39996:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup1/cli-bak
    Logical extents     9279 to 16507

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sde1
  VG Name               volgroup1
  PV Size               1.23 TB / not usable 14.18 MB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size (KByte)       32768
  Total PE              40253
  Free PE               36733
  Allocated PE          3520
  PV UUID               I1RUAu-P8Sw-waPF-b8u1-0szV-lR9D-hY1DvA

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 32767:
    FREE
  Physical extent 32768 to 33087:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup1/fatt-dig
    Logical extents     0 to 319
  Physical extent 33088 to 33887:
    FREE
  Physical extent 33888 to 37087:
    Logical volume      /dev/volgroup1/homes
    Logical extents     0 to 3199
  Physical extent 37088 to 40252:
    FREE
```

Comment: What is it that confuses you?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only move an entire PV from one VG to another, it is not going to be possible to move *all* free space from one VG to the other. But you can get there part of the way:

First, move all data on one of your PVs to some other PV:

```
pvmove -v /dev/sdb1
```

This will start moving the data to the other PVs, away from sdb1. The -v option will also ensure that you see some progress information. Once the move has finished, you can remove it from the volume group:

```
vgreduce -a
```

This will report something along the lines of `removing /dev/sdb1 from volgroup1` (sorry, it's been a while, and I don't have a machine to test on). You can then add that to the other VG:

```
vgextend volgroup2 /dev/sdb1
```

After that, `volgroup2` should have the space on sdb1 added to it.

You may be able to repeat this operation with sde1; depends on the amount of free space left in `volgroup1` after the first move (I'm too lazy to make the necessary calculations ;-). I would also recommend moving all your data into a single volume group; however, doing that will require you to create a new LV in volgroup2, create a filesystem on it, mount it, use rsync or similar to move the date over, and then destroy the old one. Clearly, this is a more risky operation.